# Why isn't UINavigationController popping UITableViewController when I touch the back button?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview, uinavigationbar

The navigationBar goes back, but the view stays the same. What gives?

Comment: try posting the code. nobody gonna get the reason seeing just a line of problem.... may be you have pushed twice or may be other reason.. Please post the code of pushing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was scrolling to the bottom of the uitableview on viewDidAppear, but if the tableView was empty, the Debugger Console would spit out: `CoreAnimation: ignoring exception: -[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]: row (-1) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).` This is because I was scrolling to the row at `indexPath = [messages count] - 1`, where messages is the table data source. I figured it was fine since it didn't crash, but when I hit back on the navigationBar after this, the navigationBar would go back, but the tableView stayed. Weird. Well, I fixed the exception by commenting out the viewDidAppear method alltogether. I could also add some logic to check if messages is empty before scrolling to the bottom of the tableView, but the scrolling isn't working exactly as I want anyhow. It shows the tableView, and then, scrolls to the bottom. I want it to be scrolled to the bottom of the tableView before the tableView even appears, like the iPhone Messages app (for text messaging) does. And I want to flash the scroll bar on the right too to show that the view is scrolled to the bottom.